# confused by strange web address especially by "ai" term in start

Tags: html, web, https, artificial-intelligence

While making online shopping,i came across a website for Live customer chat

https://ai.alimebot.daraz.pk/

"ai" in start of this web address means artificial intelligence?? If yes why and how?Infact on that link,i had chatted with a csr that was human being

Answer (score 2):

`ai.alimebot.daraz.pk` is a host name. If you are the domain owner you can create any host names and sub domain names that you want, provided you use legal characters for names.

For example, they could have created `you-are-not-expected-to-understand-this.ai.alimebot.daraz.pk`

Comment: Means it has not link or indirect mentioning of AI technology in webadrees,also when it is using the term "bot' ??

Comment: It means that the people who created the bot decided to use the domain `ai.alimebot.daraz.pk`. I could se up a domain called `abtj.random-domain-name-1234.com` if I wanted to, or even `what-is-ai.abtj.random-domain-name-1234.com`. It's just a name. There does not need to be a meaning.